# How to UNION all two tables into a temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying to combine two tables into a temp table. My goal is to have the data of both tables available in one temp table

I tried a couple of things:
1.

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM Customers.Emails
UNION ALL
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM Customers.Location
```

2. 

```
SELECT *
INTO #temp
(Select
    All column names here etc
FROM Customer.Emails
UNION
SELECT
    All column names here etc
FROM Customer.Location)
```

When I tried 2 I got this error

Msg 263, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Must specify table to select from.
Msg 1038, Level 15, State 5, Line 1
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Comment: What isn't working? The first example you posted won't probably work because there's no guarantee the tables have the same column names. The second example should work as long as the column names are identical. (but add the `FROM` after #temp ).

Comment: Provided your tables *can be unioned* your first query is fine just remove the `into #temp` from the second select.

Comment: Using * is no good idea (therefore I don't agree that any of your queries is fine). Use proper column selection, this will prevent issues when columns to one of the tables are added or columns from one of them are removed without your knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 3 methods to do the `INSERT INTO #temp`. Method 1 requires both tables to have the exact same column names and count. The other 2 methods require you to define the columns you want inserted since we aren't using `SELECT *` anymore.

```
CREATE TABLE emails (
  email_address nvarchar(50)
);
  
CREATE TABLE locations (
  email_address nvarchar(50)
);
 
INSERT INTO emails VALUES ('test@test.com');
INSERT INTO locations VALUES ('test2@test2.com');

--Method 1
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM emails
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM locations

SELECT *
FROM #temp;

--Method 2
SELECT *
INTO #temp2
FROM (
  SELECT
    email_address
  FROM emails
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    email_address
  FROM locations
) as tbl

SELECT *
FROM #temp2;

--Method 3
WITH prelim AS (
  SELECT
      email_address
    FROM emails
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        email_address
    FROM locations
)
SELECT *
INTO #temp3
FROM prelim;

SELECT *
FROM #temp3;
```

Method 1 Results:

| email_address |
| --- |
| test@test.com |
| test2@test2.com |

Method 2 Results:

| email_address |
| --- |
| test@test.com |
| test2@test2.com |

Method 3 Results:

| email_address |
| --- |
| test@test.com |
| test2@test2.com |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2rDQinb8)